# Получить дескриптор файла и изменить дату его создания WinAPI, masm32

Tags: winapi, masm

Я пишу небольшое оконное приложение, задача котороего найти каталог по заданным параметрам и затем изменить дату его создания на введенную. Я получаю путь до нужного мне каталога и затем, используя вот эту функцию

```
BOOL SetFileTime(
  HANDLE         hFile,
  const FILETIME *lpCreationTime,
  const FILETIME *lpLastAccessTime,
  const FILETIME *lpLastWriteTime
);
```

хочу установить новую дату. Проблема в том, что я не могу получить дескриптор файла. Я пытался использовать для этого CreateFile, однако он возвращает ошибку 5 (access denied). Ниже привожу фрагмент кода, в котором использую эти функции:

```
ShowFileInfo  proc uses edi row:DWORD, lpFind:DWORD    
LOCAL  lvi:LV_ITEM      
LOCAL  buffer[20]:BYTE    
LOCAL  Lft:FILETIME    ; Локальное файловое время      
LOCAL  time:SYSTEMTIME    ; Системное время       
LOCAL  Year[4]:BYTE
LOCAL  Month[2]:BYTE
LOCAL  Day[2]:BYTE
LOCAL szbuffer1[256] :BYTE
LOCAL hFile:DWORD ;тут храним дескриптор
mov  edi,lpFind   
assume  edi:ptr WIN32_FIND_DATA     
invoke  FileTimeToLocalFileTime,addr [edi].ftCreationTime,addr Lft ;получаем дату, на которую будем менять
invoke  FileTimeToSystemTime,addr Lft,addr time 
invoke  SendMessage,hEditYear, WM_GETTEXT,sizeof szbuffer1,addr szbuffer1          
invoke atodw,addr szbuffer1 
mov time.wYear, ax
invoke  SendMessage,hEditMonth, WM_GETTEXT,sizeof szbuffer1,addr szbuffer1          
invoke atodw,addr szbuffer1 
mov time.wMonth,ax
invoke  SendMessage,hEditDay, WM_GETTEXT,sizeof szbuffer1,addr szbuffer1          
invoke atodw,addr szbuffer1 
mov time.wDay, ax

invoke SystemTimeToFileTime, addr time, addr Lft ;преобразуем ее в файловое время
invoke CreateFile, addr szResult, FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0 ;получаем дескриптор файла, в szResult храним абсолютный адрес файла

mov hFile, eax
invoke SetFileTime, hFile, addr Lft, addr Lft, addr Lft ;меняем дату

    ...

ret 
ShowFileInfo  endp
```

Предпренимались так же попытки получить дескриптор путем открытия файла, но все они оканчиваются аналогичной ошибкой. Что я делаю не так? Можно ли получить дескриптор каталога другим путем?

Comment: А вы уверены, что доступ к каталогу действительно есть?

Comment: Да, каталогу предоставлен полный доступ

Comment: access denied говорит об обратном

Answer (score 0):

Попрбуйте на исполняемый файл накинуть "Выполнять от имени Администратора, всегда" в контекстном меню

Comment: К сожалению, запуск от админа ничего не поменял.